# How to push value to another object or merge object?

Tags: database, mongodb, sorting, group-by, projection

Suppose you have the following documents in my collection:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("5c7e3982a50f3b32d2668112"),
    "cat_id": 1,
    "cat_code": "YMN",
    "overall": {
        "temp_price": NumberInt(500),
    },
    "date_wise": [{
            "last_inserted_id": "11",
            "created_at": "2018-07-26",
            "overall": {
                "temp_fee": NumberInt(20),
                // .....
            },
        }, {
            "last_inserted_id": NumberInt(50),
            "created_at": "2018-08-01",
            "overall": {
                "temp_fee": NumberInt(100),
                // .....
            },
            "data": []
        }, {
            "last_inserted_id": "28",
            "created_at": "2018-08-02",
            "overall": {
                "temp_fee": NumberInt(22),
                // .....    
            },
        }
        // .....
    ]
}
```

I want output like this:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "created_at": "2018-07-26",
        "temp_fee": NumberInt(20),
    },
    "_id": {
        "created_at": "2018-08-01",
        "temp_fee": NumberInt(100),
    },
    "_id": {
        "created_at": "2018-08-02",
        "temp_fee": NumberInt(22),
    }
}
```

I am not pro in MongoDB still in a learning phase. So my efforts are as follows.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {$match : {'cat_code': 'YMN'}},
    { $project: {overall1: "$date_wise.overall"}},
    { $group: { _id: '$overall1'}},
    {'$unwind':'$_id'},
    {'$skip':0},
    {'$limit':10},
    {'$sort': {'_id.created_at' : 1}}
]);
```

I am trying to merge a single value of `overall` i.e. `created_at` and data of `overall` inside `date_wise` key. Applying to sort, skip & limit on it.

Comment: Your statement does not match your data. Do you perhaps mean "group" on `"date_wise.created_at"` adding up all values on that date for `"date_wize.overall.temp_fee"`? Or do you mean "sum all fields in `overall`"? Or really what exactly. The code is clearly not correct and your description is really not clear on whether you just want the `temp_fee` or if other values in the same object are expected. Needs clarification in the question.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. In short I want, `"created_at": "2018-07-26",
        "temp_fee": NumberInt(20),` at same level.

Comment: So you basically just want those two fields from each array element presented as the top level documents in your results? Is that it? No grouping or anything else, and just those fields.

Comment: Yes. But Sort, limit and skip required for that data. Because I am integrating pagination, searching and sorting operation on that data. and temp_fee is not the only column in date_wise.overall, there are more columns. So I want all that data to top level document in my results